# Scala regex find and replace

Tags: regex, scala

I'm having problems finding and replacing portions of a string using regex in scala.

Given the following string: `q[k6.q3]>=0 and q[dist.report][0] or q[dist.report][1] and q[10]>20`
I want to replace all the occurrences of "and" and "or" with "&&" and "||".

The regex I have come up with is: `.+\s((and|or)+)\s.+`. However, this seems to only find the last "and".

When using https://regex101.com/#pcre I tried to solve this by adding the modifiers gU, which seems to work. But I'm not sure how to use those modifiers in Scala code.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to use solution like:

```
str.replaceAll("\\sand\\s", " && ").replaceAll("\\sor\\s", " || ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the captured/matched substrings with a lambda and use an `if/else` syntax to replace with the appropriate replacement:

```
val str = "q[k6.q3]>=0 and q[dist.report][0] or q[dist.report][1] and q[10]>20"
val pattern = """\b(and|or)\b""".r
val replacedStr = pattern replaceAllIn (str, m => if (m.group(1) == "or") "||" else "&&")
println(replacedStr)
```

Result of the [code demo](http://ideone.com/GplaU9): `q[k6.q3]>=0 && q[dist.report][0] || q[dist.report][1] && q[10]>20`

Regex breakdown:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(and|or)` - either `and` or `or` letter sequences
- `\b` - the closing word boundary.

If you require whitespaces on both ends, use

```
val pattern = """ (and|or) """.r
val replacedStr = pattern replaceAllIn (str, m => if (m.group(1) == "or") " || " else " && ")
```

See [another Scala demo](http://ideone.com/m9LCWi)

Comment: Nice solution! However, I'm accepting the answer @Nyavro due to its simplicity

Comment: You decide what works for you best. Simple does not always mean efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "?" in the right places to make your patterns reluctant:

```
val line = "q[k6.q3]>=0 and q[dist.report][0] or q[dist.report][1] and q[10]>20"

val regex = ".+\\s((and|or)+)\\s.+".r

regex.findAllIn(line).toList
//Produces list with one item:
//res0: List[String] = List(q[k6.q3]>=0 and q[dist.report][0] or q[dist.report][1] and q)
```

Compared with:

```
val line = "q[k6.q3]>=0 and q[dist.report][0] or q[dist.report][1] and q[10]>20"

val regex = ".+?\\s((and|or)+)\\s.+?".r

regex.findAllIn(line).toList

//List with 3 items:
//res0: List[String] = List(q[k6.q3]>=0 and q, [dist.report][0] or q, [dist.report][1] and q)
```